# Can I get Reopen votes from other Bidge players?

Tags: discussion

[This bidding question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/29940/bridge-bidding-response-after-rho-overcalls-at-2-level-and-you-have-stoppers-and), while not great, still inquires on a topic that can be addressed sensibly. Note that my answer steps the reader through a logical process of analyzing possible responses according to the priority which bridge experts have developed over the past century, as I understand it. I believe it is worthwhile hearing the opinions of other strong players, so as to allow the Stack Overflow paradigm to work - let the best answer float to the top.

Comment: Whilst I agree the topic can be addressed sensibly, I feel it's a bit premature to ask for it to be reopened - it might in fact never be reopen-worthy, given the querent's account is apparently deleted. Despite the topic's broachability, there are a number of clarifying questions sitting in the comments that highlight places the question needs improvement in, and the asker's unlikely to update it. It may be cleared up one day, but we close based on the _current_ state of a question, which is: unclear. Could you suggest why we'd reopen this? Have you considered creating a canon question?

Comment: @doppelgreener: No wonder actual bridge players keep abandoning this site. Have you ever played the game? If I delete ***my*** comment does the question become worthy of re-opening? Three of the question closers have ***zero*** questions, answers, and votes on bridge or bidding tags - WTF are they doing making decisions on a question for a game they are ignorant about?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I wonder if that actually should lead to a meta question about the responsibility of reviewers. I skip review tasks having to do with bridge because I know nothing about the game (along with 40k and games that have complex rules systems). It would surprise me to find out that multiple users were making close votes on complex games they had no knowledge of, and I would consider it to be detrimental to the healthy operation of the site if answerable (although bad) questions were being closed as _unclear_ because of it.

Comment: @Pieter Whatever axe you have to grind, grind it with someone else. Those are *your* clarification requests, and there's several questions there. I'm simply asking for a compelling case to reopen it, when there appears to be a compelling case from yourself why it should be closed as unclear (it needs clarification).

Comment: I would say with your comment on the question asking for more information that keeping it closed until those questions start getting answered would be good.

Answer (score 1):

The question you are referring to is missing a lot of information about the entire situation that is needed to answer the question. You even mentioned that in a comment on the question. While your answer may be generic enough in order to provide some answers as a site we need to ensure that there is enough information on questions to provide solid answers.

Also with the user having deleted their account there will be no way to get the information needed to provide a clear question that can get a clear answer.

Comment: And you are knowledgeable about Bridge how? I see no revealed expertise on either Bridge or Bidding in your profile. have you been holding out on us?

Comment: Based on the comment you posted on the question and the lack of any details in the question. You don't have to be an expert to spot a really bad question.

Comment: So you are going to punish all Bridge contributors on this site because I thought the question could be improved, and that OP could be educated about how to post a great question instead of merely a poor one. My comments are addressed to OP, being comments on the original question, and are an educational process aimed at OP on the importance of those facts in evaluating  one's bid.

Comment: In fact the argument can be made, and has been made by other non-bridge contributors on this site, that if all those questions had been answered the question is a poor fit for the site by virtue of being of no interest to other readers. Your overwhelming ignorance of the game Bridge  is why you should ***Skip*** questions on tags you know nothing about.

Comment: Putting a question on hold is what should happen for bad questions, when they are fixed they can be reopened. The simple fact is that is a bad question that needs improvement.  If other people in the bridge tag agree with it being open they would have voted so. And remember tag knowledge is not required for reviewing otherwise they would never be completed on a small site like this.